# issue with JSTL Hashset

Tags: java, jstl

The below code is not working

```
<c:forEach var="row" varStatus="rowCount" begin="1" end="10">

 <c:set var="entry" scope="request" value="${session.entry.mileStones[rowCount.count]}"/>
 or

<c:set var="entry" scope="request" value="${entry.mileStones[rowCount.count]}"/>

</c:forEach>
```

where , Entry.getMileStones ====> HashSet is properly set in action class in session scope.

```
getSession().setAttribute("entry", entry);
```

Any idea..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some problems I see with the example provided:

- As far as I know, JSTL and EL syntax doesn't work for sets, only maps. This makes sense, because there's no concept of retrieving the value for a key in a set (as the value *is* the key). Based the on the example you've provided, it looks like you might actually want the data structure to be either a list or a map.
- It looks like you're trying to set a scoped value (entry) on the basis of the same value. Even if this will work, I doubt that it's what you want to do. Consider a different variable name for the second variable.
- You can't iterate with a foreach without providing a collection to iterate over. There must be an items attribute with the foreach tag.

Answer (score 0):

You are using different scopes. Change scope to session.